# ASP.NET Global.asax - IE conditional stylesheet in bundle

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

In our application we bundle styles together in the `Global.asax` `Application_Start`, e.g.

```
' CSS Bundle
Dim brandRef = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SiteBrandRef")
Dim cssBundle = New StyleBundle("~/content/css")
cssBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/CSS", "*.css")
cssBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/CSS/" & brandRef, "*.css")
cssBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/CSS/" & brandRef & "/design", "*.css")
cssBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/CSS/" & brandRef & "/layout", "*.css")
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(cssBundle)
```

Is there a way to use this pattern with IE7, IE8 only stylesheets? Perhaps a separate bundle? I don't think there's a way to do user agent detection in `Global.asax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do in the Global.asax. This must be done in client code.

Here is a very good article on [IE version specific CSS](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

> Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<pre>< !--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

> Target IE 8 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I suspected it to be as such - we use this conditional pattern in the master page, and shall continue to do so if it is the only way!